# Is there any way to get the source application (Process) of file dragdrop in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, if I drag a file from FileExplorer or TotalCommander(3rd party file explorer) and drop to my application, my application can get the Process of the FileExplorer/TotalCommander. Is there any way I can achieve this in C# with "DragDrop.Drop"?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**, not for 3rd party apps outside your control

The long answer is **maybe**. You would have to hook DoDragDrop() or dll inject for every running process as there is no normal other way to discover the source. This information is purposely abstracted.

However the biggest question to ask yourself is why do you want to do this, as this could easily be an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)